# Binary Logistic Regression + moderation - understanding outcome

Tags: r, statistics, rstudio, logistic-regression, glm

Hello so I'm working on a project where I'm looking at a binary outcome, here Cannabis use (so Y/N answers) and want to see if it's predicted by Emotional Dysregulation (continuous variable). I then want to see if the relationship is moderated by a third variable: Parent Monitoring. This is on a scale of 3-14, I divided it into low, moderate and high, to make it more clear. 
I used this code

```
modelWeed <- glm(Cannabis ~ (EmotionalDysregulation * TieredMonitor) + Gender, data = DATA, na.action = "na.exclude", family = "binomial")
summary(modelWeed)
```

So part one of this question is if this is right? (Am I controlling for Gender this way?)
Part two is my confusion with the product. The monitoring is in three parts but only the last two appear in the interactions (from what I see this appears normal but why does it happen? how am I supposed to find out if there are relationships for the first?)

```
Coefficients:
                                      Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)                           -3.68218    0.28208 -13.054  < 2e-16 ***
EmotionalDysregulation                 0.50755    0.12188   4.164 3.12e-05 ***
TieredMonitor2                        -0.22447    0.45224  -0.496  0.61964    
TieredMonitor3                        -2.34199    0.71856  -3.259  0.00112 ** 
Gender                                 0.02648    0.09871   0.268  0.78853    
EmotionalDysregulation:TieredMonitor2 -0.22807    0.24743  -0.922  0.35666    
EmotionalDysregulation:TieredMonitor3  0.39743    0.37011   1.074  0.28291
```

Is there a way to have TieredMonitor1 appear? 
Sorry, I'm sure this is basic, I am only beginning and find this more intuitive than SPSS, but still find my hurdles.

Comment: This has been discussed many times before. The first level (the reference) is in the intercept, the intercept contains all the references for all the factors.

Comment: @user2974951 Sorry I just struggled to understand it in term of other people's data. What does your last sentence mean in practice?

Comment: @user2974951 how to i get coefficients and probabilities for this category?

Comment: You cannot have at the same time all the levels of a factor variable and intercept, otherwise you would have full collinearity. See [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/307298/why-is-the-ols-assumption-no-perfect-multicollinearity-so-vital) for some details.

Comment: ok so hopefully this helps explains a few things. The coefficients you see in the summary() tell you the effect of each variable, for example,EmotionalDysregulation tells you each 1 increase in EmotionalDysregulation, how the log-odds of cannabis use changes

Comment: When you have a categorical variable, it tells you how the log-odds change w.r.t to the reference. Now if your question is more about whether TieredMonitor plays a role at all, you do an anova(modelWeed), this tells you how useful each variable is

Comment: Looking at your coefficients, TieredMonitor should be significant under the anova.